# html image id and canvas

Tags: javascript, html

Hi there I have a simple question I can'[t seem to find the answer to on google. I'm trying to draw an image on a canvas. I originally used the "new" constructor ( ballPic = new Image(); ballPic.src = "ball.png" ) which worked when drawing on my canvas, but I needed to do some scaling and wasn't sure if I could attach a css id to the object. So I instead tried to use the image tag and did the rest in css.

However using a variable that way doenst seem to work with my canvas' drawing:

```
ballPic = '<img id="soccerBall">';
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(BallPic, -25, -25);
```

Is this because assigning a variable like ballPic =  is not the same as being the element itself like when using the constructor? How would I pass it other than attaching it to the document and using getElementbyID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep using the `Image` constructor and still scale the image. There's another method overload of the `drawImage` function:

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images):

> The second variant of the drawImage() method adds two new parameters and lets us place scaled images on the canvas.
>
> `drawImage(image, x, y, width, height)`
>
> This adds the width and height parameters, which indicate the size to which to scale the image when drawing it onto the canvas.

I would recommend you check out that page, it has a lot of good information, like

- Using `data:` urls
- Handling image loading
- Loading still frames from videos
- Slicing
- Examples gallore

Answer (score 0):

Create an image, handle the onload event, in which you update the canvas size to the scaled size of the image, then drawImage with a scale.

```
var scale = 2            ;
var ballPic = new Image();

ballPic.onload = function drawImage() {
     var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
     c.width  = ballPic.width * scale  ;
     c.height = ballPic.height * scale ; 
     var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
     ctx.scale(scale, scale)   ;
     ctx.drawImage(ballPic, 0, 0);  
};

ballPic.src =
   'http://melinabeachturtlehatchery.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/turtle4.jpg';
```

the fiddle is here :

http://jsbin.com/etemox/1/edit

Comment: I think it's the first time I see a non-anonymous function being used directly on a event call vector :)

Comment: :) i quite often name functions for the purpose of clarity, debugging, and performance or memory profiling... It is somtimes quite usefull.